# TableViewCell doesn't show data on first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode6

I have two `UILabels` on my `UITableViewCell`.

I am using storyboard and I have these labels in custom cell as shown below:

[image]

My `cellForRowAtIndex` method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cell";

NSLog(@"index = %ld",indexPath.row);  //This logs correct 0,1,2 ..and so on

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}
UILabel *lblCellTitle = (UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
UILabel *lblCellDetail = (UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag:2];

lblCellTitle.text = [arrtableDataHeading objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //this array contain valid values
lblCellDetail.text = [filterdInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //this array contain valid values

return cell;

}
```

My Problem is when First time I open My controller the data is shown from second Index and in last I see the The custom label name as shown below:

[image]

**And when I scroll then only data is updated and In random order I am not able to get the data in right order.**

When I debug When The `indexPath` is 0 aim getting nil in `UILabel` but when It becomes 1 I am getting correct value.

[image]
[image]

Some one told me using cell.ContentView in place of self.view will solve my problem. But I am confused How can this be.

Comment: did you set the cell identifier in Storyboard ("cell")?

Comment: yes I have set that @Mahesh

Answer (score 2):

As i would recommend that the way you are following is not correct.
As per MVC, your view classes and your controller classes should be different if you are making something custom. In your case you can make a UITableViewCell class and than use its object to initialise your cell.

```
CommentsTableViewCell *cell = (CommentsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"comments cell"];
    cell.lblName.text = @"String data";
    NSString *dateString = @"String data";
    cell.lblCommentTime.text = @"String data";
    cell.imgDp.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"String data"];
    cell.lblCommentDuration.text = @"String data";
```

In above code CommentsTableViewCell is a custom class for UITableViewCell.
Hope you will find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing these lines,

```
UILabel *lblCellTitle = (UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
UILabel *lblCellDetail = (UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag:2];
```

with

```
UILabel *lblCellTitle = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
UILabel *lblCellDetail = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
```

If it is not working, let me know.